# Manga where MC in challenger to take curses

Tags: story-identification, manga

The only thing I remember about this manga is that the MC was in a zone or something where the challenge was that you had to take curses. There were different kinds of curses, one where everything you ate tasted awful, one where you couldn't see/hear, and so on.

One character that I remember is a girl in this zone who had long red hair and had a curse where she couldn't bath/shower or so.

Comment: "*a girl in this zone who had long red hair*" is the manga in full/partial color?

Comment: I think it was full

Comment: What sort of world was the story set in? Medieval Europe? Ancient China? A more technologically advanced civilisation?

Comment: i cant remember sry

Comment: Was the MC male or female?